# ruleset.trace.enabled=true but trace not enabled for Business Rules on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I am trying to trace my rules that are deployed on the Business Rules service on Bluemix. I set the ruleset property ruleset.trace.enabled to true, however, this does not seem to enable tracing (like it did for ODM). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently tracing is disabled by default for rules executing on the Business Rules service. Using the ruleset properties ruleset.trace.enabled, ruleset.sequential.trace.enabled and filters does not enable tracing.

Instead, I had to add trace filter tags to the payload request. There are more details at [How can I trace rules in the Business Rules service on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639786/how-can-i-trace-rules-in-the-business-rules-service-on-bluemix)