# View contents of input parameters for the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I need to view the input parameter values for the rulesets executed by the Business Rules service on Bluemix. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could view the input objects by [enabling tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639786/how-can-i-trace-rules-in-the-business-rules-service-on-bluemix) when executing the rules. I set the element `trac:inputParameters` to `true` for XML, or `infoInputParameters` to `true` for JSON, for example:

```
"__TraceFilter__": {
"infoInputParameters": true   }
```